# Retrieving os.listdir using network path

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get user input to get a computer name and then use os.listdir to retrieve the folders in that directory - specifically the user folder (C:\users).. I have written the following code and does not seem to pull any results.  There is no error received when running the code "Process finished with exit code 0"

```
import os
def listdirectory():
    computername = input("What is the computer name? ")
    completepath = r"\\" + computername + r"\C$\users"
    os.listdir(completepath)


listdirectory()
```

I am trying to find out if os.listdir can be used this way if not which way i should go about writing this.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you're doing something with that output!

```
import os
from typing import List

def listdirectory() -> List[str]:
    computername = input("What is the computer name? ")
    completepath = fr"\\{computername}\C$\Users"
    return os.listdir(completepath)

print(listdirectory())
```

For clarification, your example code did not have a `return` statement from the function, so `None` is implicitly returned.  Without the `return` and without the `print`, you will not see output.  This behavior may be different from the REPL.

Comment: @C.Nivs I like to annotate my code for readability (in general).  It expresses what actually gets returned from the function.

Comment: I understand that it documents what is returned, I think it just adds unnecessary info to OP's question, where they might think that the type signature is needed to *return* the value, when really they just haven't used `return` to give anything back from the function itself